# Remove white space in images

Tags: html, css, image

I have many images and my code is the following.

There is white space in some of the images in top or left of some images. I couldn't find how to fix it. I've set width and max-width.

I save images as tmb file. Is it possible to be due to it?

What should I fix? Thanks!

```css
.pbombd-thumbnail {
     float:left; 
     margin-top: 10px; 
     margin-right: 17px; 
     width: 220px; 
     padding: 0px !important;
     border-radius: 4px; 
     border: 0px;
    }

.pbombd-img-thumb 
{
 
 max-width:218.4px; 
 max-height: 178px;
 min-width: 218.4px;
 min-height: 178px;
 margin:0px;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail pbombd-thumbnail">

    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97350&w=350&h=350" class="pbombd-img-thumb"/>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Edited:
I forgot to add this css in question:

`.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}`

Comment: Are your images same height and width?

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block;` to `.pbombd-img-thumb`.  Displaying as `inline` or `inline-block` can cause extra space.

```css
.pbombd-thumbnail {
     float:left; 
     margin-top: 10px; 
     margin-right: 17px; 
     width: 220px; 
     padding: 0px !important;
     border-radius: 4px; 
     border: 0px;
        background-color: orange;
    }

.pbombd-img-thumb 
{
        display: block;
 max-width:218.4px; 
 max-height: 178px;
 min-width: 218.4px;
 min-height: 178px;
 margin:0px;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail pbombd-thumbnail">

    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97350&w=350&h=350" class="pbombd-img-thumb"/>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried it but it's the same. I edited my question. I added css for thumbnail class.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the css of the img element. Some media elements have white space.